# Do I need to use a ELIF function for a nested IF function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested

I'm trying out this nested IF function in google docs: `=IF(AA2<0.2,0,IF(0.2<=AA2<0.4,1,IF(0.4<=AA2<0.6,2,IF(0.6<=AA2<0.8,2,IF(0.8<=AA2<=1,3,"WRONG")))))`

However when the function is used on values such as 0.432, or 0.8, it automatically shows me the "WRONG" value. How can I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is syntactically correct, but there is a semantic issue: `0.2 <= AA2 < 0.4` will be evaluated as `(0.2 <= AA2) < 0.4`, i.e., `false < 0.4` or `true < 0.4`. The end result is that the expression will always be evaluated as `false`.

The easiest way to make it work is probably to use `ifs()` instead of `if()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  AA2 < 0.2, 0, 
  AA2 < 0.4, 1, 
  AA2 < 0.6, 2, 
  AA2 < 0.8, 2, 
  AA2 <= 1, 3, 
  true, "WRONG" 
)
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much! This formula worked. Is ```ifs()``` basically better for nested functions compared to ```if()```?

Comment: In this use case, `ifs()` is easier to read and understand.